# Compilation error in VPL but not in Intellij (Java, University Assignment)

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors, double, data-conversion

My issue here is that my code runs perfectly fine and does what I want in Intellij, but not in VPL. The problem occurs while trying to convert an int to a double in the tailLength calculation.

> Error: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int,double
> found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

So the double seems to be missing, here is the code:

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private double tailLength;



   public Dog(String name, String breed, int age, int weight, double tailLength) {
       this.name = name;
       this.breed = breed;
       this.age = age;
       this.weight = weight;
       this.tailLength = tailLength;
   }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed(){
       return breed;
    }

    public int getAge() {
       return age;
    }

    public void increaseAge(){
       age++;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
       return weight;
    }

    public double getTailLength() {
       if (getBreed().equals("Dachshund") || getBreed().equals("Tax")){
           tailLength = 3.7;
           return tailLength;
       } else {
           tailLength = (double)getAge() * ((double)getWeight() / 10.0);
           return tailLength;
       }
    }

    public String toString(){
      return getName() + " " + getBreed() + " " + getAge() + " " + getWeight()+ " " + getTailLength();
    }

}
```

Comment: That class looks fine, can you post the code that creates the object?  From the error message it looks like you missed an argument to the constructor, though how that could possibly work in IntelliJ is certainly interesting.

Comment: The error tells you specifically _where_ the offending line is, and it's not in this class.

Comment: @stridecolossus yes that's the problem, we are not allowed to see the code that creates the object, it's hidden in the VPL (?) which makes it all the more confusing since we are supposed to create the code above for our teacher's code which we are not allowed to see... So I was thinking if there might be another way to convert the integers to doubles in another way

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've got the wrong end of the stick here?  The error indicates that the VPL (whatever that is) is calling your constructor with **four** values (String, String, int, int).  There is no double being passed and therefore no need to convert it.

The whole point of the exercise is to *calculate* the tail length, hence the `getTailLength()` method.  Remove the `tailLength` constructor parameter (and the class member which would be redundant).

Comment: Yup that did it! Thanks a million!